# i don`t know what to do now with the problem invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 20)pylint(syntax-error)

Tags: json, xcode, helper

I'm trying to build my own desktop assistant and got problem with first line. Checking if i got extra space or line but all looks ok, could you please check  if anything is wrong?
I did add my script in progress and picture. Thank you all !!

```py
import speech_recognition as sr
import os
import sys
import re
import webbrowser
import smtplib
import requests
import subprocess
from pyowm import OWM
import youtube_dl
import vlc
import urllib
import urllib2
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib2 import urlopen
import wikipedia
import random
from time import strftime


def sofiaResponse (audio);
    "speaks audio passed as argument"
    print(audio)
    for line in audio.splitlines():
        os.system("say" + audio)

def myCommand ():
    "listens for commands"
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print('Say something...')
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=1)
        audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        command = r.recognize_google(audio).lower()
        print('You said: ' + command + '\n')
    #loop back to continue listening
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print('Error, help me error')
        command = myCommand();
        return command

def assistant (command):
    "if statements for executing commands"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyYio.png)

Answer (score 0):

On line 22, you made a typo :

```py
def sofiaResponse (audio);
```

should be

```py
def sofiaResponse (audio):
```